# Pull data from one sheet (has a locked cell) to another sheet (has a locked cell) every day automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a dynamic Google spreadsheet to which I add one more sheet every day. I want to take the data from sheet1 cell D96 (a protect cell) to sheet2 cell D3 (a protect cell) every day. I found a [script](http://www.google.com.tr/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687779/copy-value-from-specific-cell-in-google-spreadsheet-to-another-via-button&sa=U&ei=RFtiU9qSLaKU4ATGrYGwBg&ved=0CB8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNGaXUTJARRhIipMXrfdSAW9U_BBXQ) and I edited it to:

```
function devir() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var sheetidx = sheet.getIndex()-1 ;
  var nextSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[sheetidx+1];
  var val = nextSheet.getRange('d96').copyTo(sheet.getRange('d3'),{contentsOnly:true})
}
```

and it is working perfectly with a edit trigger for me (owner) but my problem is that the people with whom I am sharing this document (can edit) get this error:

> "There was a problem while   You don't have permission for this action"

How can I solve this problem or can I change the script to a custom function? like: write d3 cell `=devir(d96) take the data before sheet`.

[image: pull the date one page to next page]

Comment: does anyone have any answers?

Comment: well can i pull data from one sheet to another sheet every day automatically? (has not a locked cell). because this code give an error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined. (line 8, file "Code")" and than number format change into word format and i cant sum.

Comment: Perhaps you can look at the answer I gave to your other question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an simple on edit trigger use an installable trigger as it runs with the trigger creator credentials.